# Configuring LDAP Authentication in Odoo

Tags: ldap, odoo-9, synology

I have two servers:

1st server: **Odoo 9** application hosted in **Amazon EC2**
2nd server: **LDAP server** hosted in my **Synology NAS** which is in a **local area network**

Right now, I would like to authenticate all the Odoo users by the LDAP server.

**Things that I have done**

1. I have installed the Authentication via LDAP (auth_ldap) module in Odoo
2. [Configured LDAP Parameters in Odoo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZ62k.gif). Note: Actual IP address and domain were altered due to security issue. Need someone to check if the configuration values  are entered correctly.
3. Open the port 389 in my office network to public and forwarded it to the LDAP server.
4. Tested using [*ldapsearch* command line in Amazon EC2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gxat7.gif) to ensure that both servers can communicate.

Somehow I am still not able to login using the LDAP user login in Odoo. What did I do wrong? Is there any other way to find out if Odoo is communicating with the LDAP server?

Comment: I'm trying to install Authentication via LDAP, but I'm using Docker. Its easy to get Odoo up and running but when I try to install this addon nothing seems to happen.  Were you able to get the LDAP server working? How did you install the addon? Where did you find the screen in step 2?

Comment: The LDAP configuration can be found at Settings \ General Settings \ Configure your company data \ Configuration (Tab) \ LDAP Parameters. Unfortunately, I couldn't get it to work properly. I gave up at the end and used the standard login authentication only.